# How to find specific index by its content

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
wordlist = open(r'C:\Users\islam\Desktop\10k most passwords.txt')

for words in wordlist:
    line = (words.split())  
    for count, ele in enumerate(wordlist, 1):
        x=(([count, ele]))
        print(x)
```

The output :

> [9994, 'hugohugo\n']

> [9995, 'eighty\n']

> [9996, 'epson\n']

> [9997, 'evangeli\n']

> [9998, 'eeeee1\n']

> [9999, 'eyphed']

How could I find index 0 by typing its content , like input **9995** and the output be :

> [9995, 'eighty\n']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach:

```py
with open('path/to/file') as file:
    data = file.readlines()


while True:
    try:
        user_input = int(input('Enter index:'))
        if user_input < 1:
            raise ValueError
        print(data[user_input - 1].strip())
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        print('Invalid index value')
```

I would say pretty simple since if You split by readlines it already is a list and can be accessed using indexes (subtract 1 to "start" index from 1), the rest of the code that includes error handling is for user convenience.

Simply for getting a value from a "hardcoded" index:

```py
with open('path/to/file') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

index = 5    
print(data[index - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks its worked !! ,  I wish someday be like you , I spent 1 hour thinking how to do this all I can say exquisite

Comment: there is problem when I remove the input and add number in value of user_input make endless loop with the word

Comment: @Islamhamdi well, yes, the reason it doesn't do that with `input()` is because input stops everything and waits until user inputs something, if You want to specify index in code, just do `print(data[put_index_here - 1].strip())` (`.strip()` is not necessary, it just removes that trailing newline) (`put_index_here` just put the actual integer like: `print(data[5 - 1])`) (`-1` to "start" index from 1) (and the code in that case could be just like 3 lines)

Comment: I updated the code to inlcude a sample of what I mentioned in the other comment

Comment: i have removed the while loop and its worked

Comment: there wasn't any need for while TRUE statement

Comment: ok, but if You are entering the index in code then there isn't that much of a need to have all that try and except stuff, You can just do as I did in my answer, at the bottom I added code for if you want to specify index in code, tho You can keep those try except if you really need

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
list.index(element, start, end)

element - the element to be searched
start (optional) - start searching from this index
end (optional) - search the element up to this index
```

At the place of list you write your list name.
I think this may help